# Changed mysql charset to utf8, non-latin characters already in database now unreadable

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have several years of data in the DB, which is 99% Latin characters. Recently, I've added the following after the mysql connection:

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
```

Now all the existing data in the database that is composed of asian, Hebrew, etc characters is no longer readable and appears as garbage data.

How can I fix the data in the DB so its readable with a utf8 charset?

The table charset was always utf8. The only thing that changed is the fact that there is a charset set during the connection (as shown above), and before that line was absent.

The table creation  is fairly basic, the collation is utf8_general_ci

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 COLUMNS + INDEXES
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please post your `CREATE TABLE`-statement, so we can have a look at your tables encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now have data that is double-encoded, and you are going to need to fix the data before you can read it on a connection that uses utf8 as the charset.

Here's a blog that explain in detail how to fix your data:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/16/utf8-data-on-latin1-tables-converting-to-utf8-without-downtime-or-double-encoding/

Comment: The table was utf8 from the start, the only thing that was different is the fact that the charset was not specified during the connection to the server. Additionally, our DB cluster is several machines and the dataset is quite large. Are there any other ways to fix this on a row-by-row basis?

Comment: Found the solution in the comments: convert(cast(convert(name using latin1) as binary) using utf8)